# Ubuntu does not render on full resolution on Ubuntu 22.04 and 20.04

Tags: 20.04, display, display-resolution, wayland, 22.04

EDIT. Solved!
The cause of the problem was Legacy Boot. I set Legacy Boot disabled and Secure Boot enabled (apparently both should be disabled to fix the problem but for me disabling the Legacy Boot did the job).
Thanks to my dear friend who helped me fix this.

---

---

Original post.

Today I installed Ubuntu 22.04 (had the same issue on 20.04 though) next to my Windows and I found a strange bug.

My desktop seems to be doubled, as you can see in the following screenshot:

[image: doubled desktop]

The display is not rendered on the full screen, no matter what resolution I choose. There is a black bar on the right and I can see the very same desktop twice (one above the other). When I move my mouse the same movement can be seen on both of these desktops.

At the bottom of the screen we can see the second desktop that is mirroring the first (top) one:

[image: second desktop at the bottom of the screen]

I tried changing resolution, adding a custom resolution, messing with the scale, however, nothing has helped so far. Here is a screenshot of my *Display* settings:

[image: Display settings]

My GNOME version is 42.0 and the issue appears both on Wayland and X11 (tried both).

Here is my system's hardware:

- HP ProOne 600 G5 21.5-in All-in-One
- 8 GB RAM
- i3-8100 3.6 GHz
- Intel UHD Graphics 630
- 256 GB SSD

If you have any idea how to fix this, please help.

Comment: Please don'n put SOLVED in the topic. Instead make a proper answer and then mark that as a solution.